# Create Group ID in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, grouping

I have a table such as:

| GROUP | STUDENT | GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 3 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 | 9 |
| 4 | 2 | 8 |
| 4 | 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 10 |

Where the groups have different lengths.

How one could assign a Group ID for every 2 categories (or n) of variable `GROUP` in SQL to get a column `GROUP_ID` such as:

| GROUP_ID | GROUP | STUDENT | GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 9 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 | 8 |
| 3 | 5 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 6 | 1 | 10 |

Comment: Just a note: `group` is a keyword in SQL and should probably not be used as a column name.

Comment: Even a _reserved_ keyword...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use arithmetic:

```
select ceiling(groupcol / 2.0)
```

If your `groupcol` has gaps, then you can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select ceiling(dense_rank() over (order by groupcol) / 2.0)
```

Comment: I have a groupcol not ordered and can assume any integer value, `ceiling` would work?

Answer (score 0):

If `GROUP` numeration doesn't have gaps, then common formula for any `N` for `GROUP_ID` is: `(GROUP - 1) / N + 1`.
If you do have gaps, you may use `dense_rank() over (order by group)` instead of `GROUP`.